# deliver token manually (in addition to the owin configuration way)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I have actually an asp.net website application, that can deliver token to an user with the following way :

1. the user logs into the application, go to a specific page and obtains a clientid and a clientsecret.
2. then, he calls the following api "....api/token" by giving clientid and clientsecret (client credentials grant type) to get the token.

This is the associated code :

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyApp.Web.App_Start.OwinStartup))]

namespace MyApp.Web.App_Start
{
    public class OwinStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OwinWebApiStartup.Configuration(app);            
        }
    }
}

public static class OwinWebApiStartup
{
    public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var provider = //my provider implementation;
        var oauthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20),
            Provider = provider,
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oauthServerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AccessTokenProvider = //my provider implementation,
        });
   }
}
```

This is working nicely. But I would like to add a new feature, where a javascript client code, not an user anymore, would like to call my apis, and so it will need to have a token, but do not have a clientid and clientsecret.
This is my idea :

Create a new api endpoint, (only this one will be reachable by my javascript client code without token, and there, the code will generate a token (thanks to the username of the current user connected) and return this one (that will
be the same that an user could have obtained with the existing method) to be used by the javascript client code

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem in the past. I solved this via querystring, cause owin could only provide one token ressource. In fact it makes sense to rely on owin and on not implementing your own code.

My pseudo solution:

```
KeyValuePair<string, string[]> typePair = ctx.Request.Query.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "type");
LoginType? loginType = GetLoginType(typePair);
[...]
switch (loginType)
        {
            case LoginType.User:
            [...]
            ////within this routine you could set your claims depending on your needs
```

If you get another solution, I'd be grateful for sharing